# how to create and download excel document using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, openxml

How to create and download excel document using asp.net ?

The purpose is to use xml, linq or whatever to send an excel document to a customer via a browser.

Edit : **Use case**

The customer load a gridview ( made with ajax framework ) in a browser, the gridview is directly linked to an sql database.
I put a button 'export to excel' to let customer save this gridview data on his computer ansd i would like to launch a clean download of an excel.

The solutions proposed here are not clean, like send an html document and change the header to excel document etc, i'm searching a simple solution on codeplex right now, i will let you know.

Comment: This is quite vague.  Do you already have the document, and you just need to know how to send the appropriate headers to tell the browser "force download...don't display" or "this is an excel file", or do you need to generate a doc in excel format based on data in your app and then serve it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Starter kit

First i have downloaded the [**Open XML Format SDK 2.0**](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c6e744e5-36e9-45f5-8d8c-331df206e0d0&DisplayLang=en).

It comes with 3 useful tools in :

C:\Program Files\Open XML Format SDK\V2.0\tools

- `DocumentReflector.exe` wich auto
  generate the c# to build a
  spreadsheet from the code.
- `OpenXmlClassesExplorer.exe` display
  Ecma specification and the class
  documentation (using an MSDN style
  format).
- `OpenXmlDiff.exe` graphically compare
  two Open XML files and search for
  errors.

I suggest anyone who begin to **rename** ***.xlsx*** **to** **.zip**, so you can see the XML files who drive our spreadsheet ( for the example our sheets are in "xl\worksheets" ).

---

### The code

**Disclaimer** : I have stolen all the code from an [**MSDN technical article**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd452407.aspx) ;D

The following code use an *.xlsx template i made manually to be able to modify it.

Namespaces references

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;


// Database object
        DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();

        // Make a copy of the template file.
        File.Copy(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\project.Web\Clients\Handlers\oxml-tpl\livreurs.xlsx", @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\project.Web\Clients\Handlers\oxml-tpl\generated.xlsx", true);

        // Open the copied template workbook. 
        using (SpreadsheetDocument myWorkbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\project.Web\Clients\Handlers\oxml-tpl\generated.xlsx", true))
        {
            // Access the main Workbook part, which contains all references.
            WorkbookPart workbookPart = myWorkbook.WorkbookPart;

            // Get the first worksheet. 
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.ElementAt(2);

            // The SheetData object will contain all the data.
            SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();

            // Begining Row pointer                       
            int index = 2;

            // Database results
            var query = from t in db.Clients select t;

            // For each item in the database, add a Row to SheetData.
            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                // Cell related variable
                string Nom = item.Nom;

                // New Row
                Row row = new Row();
                row.RowIndex = (UInt32)index;

                // New Cell
                Cell cell = new Cell();
                cell.DataType = CellValues.InlineString;
                // Column A1, 2, 3 ... and so on
                cell.CellReference = "A"+index;

                // Create Text object
                Text t = new Text();
                t.Text = Nom;

                // Append Text to InlineString object
                InlineString inlineString = new InlineString();
                inlineString.AppendChild(t);

                // Append InlineString to Cell
                cell.AppendChild(inlineString);

                // Append Cell to Row
                row.AppendChild(cell);

                // Append Row to SheetData
                sheetData.AppendChild(row);

                // increase row pointer
                index++;                

            }

            // save
            worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();

        }
```

I havent finished yet, my second job is to auto download the spreadsheet after modification.

---

Finally, i redirect the user to my generated spredsheet (from my aspx)

```
 context.Response.Redirect("Oxml-tpl/generated.xlsx");
```

Comment: Thanks for the (borrowed!) in depth example. Needed to do a quick job regarding reading tons of excel. This did it for me with the least resistance

Comment: Thanks Its working as expected. I have one doubt if i have more than 30 columns then how can i write to excel. for few columns we can write in foreach . Please suggest me.

Comment: after days of search , this was the perfect solution
It words perfectly with WCF (don't forget to add iis permission to file)
and it doesn't need Excel installed on server

Answer (score 2):

just set Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel" and your page will rendered as an excel sheet on the clients browser

[Sample code here](http://www.thaicreate.com/asp.net/asp.net-excel-application-vnd.ms-excel.html)

Comment: but for simplicity's sake, output any data you want in excel's "grid" in html tables

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways of handling this, depending on how extensive the Excel functionality is. Binoj's answer works if the Excel is just a spreadsheet and has no direct Excel functionality built in. The client can add functionality, concats, etc. These are "dumb" excel docs until the client does soemthing.

To create a more full featured Excel doc, you havve two basic choices that I can think of offhand.

1. Use either the office components (re: bad) to create an excel document, or a third party component, like SoftArtisan's ExcelWriter. Great component, but there is a cost.
2. Use a control on the page that allows export to Excel. Most vendors of ASSP.NET controls have this functionality on their grids.

Option #1 allows you pretty much all functionality of Excel. Option #2 is a bit more limited, at least in the controls I have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Good article on how top export to excel from Erika Ehrli
http://blogs.msdn.com/erikaehrli/archive/2009/01/30/how-to-export-data-to-excel-from-an-asp-net-application-avoid-the-file-format-differ-prompt.aspx