# Create an Excel file on server and send to a browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file

I'm using EPPlus to create an excel file on the server. The problem is that I wan't the file to be saved on the clients harddrive and when I the application up on a server I believe this will save the file on the server harddrive.

Is it possible to send this file back to the client/browser some how?

```
public void CreateAnnuityExcelSheet(List<Calculation> cList, FormCollection form, int DTCyear)
{
    List<Calculation> newList = new List<Calculation>();
    newList.Add(cList.First()); //Getting the values for the first row
    var StartValue = newList[0].StartValue;
    var radio = form["advanceOrArrears"];
    string fileName = newList[0].CalculationName;
    string path = @"C:\ExcelFiles\" + fileName + ".xlsx"; //Path for the file
    FileInfo info = new FileInfo(path);
    info.Directory.Create(); //If C:\ExcelFiles does not exist, create it
    if (!info.Exists)
    {
        using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(info))
        {
            ExcelWorksheet ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(fileName);
            //Styles for the sheet
            package.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, save to the server's disk and once complete, send the file as a response.

Comment: How do I send this as a response?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to send the bytes as File to browser. If your library for creating Excel files allows you to save to stream (like for example [ClosedXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/) does) then you can do in your MVC action

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();
workbook.SaveAs(stream);
stream.Position = 0;

return File(stream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet.main+xml", "file.xlsx");
```

If you can't save it to memory stream then save it to server's disc and then you can just pass file path and content type to `return File()`.

Comment: I have tried this now and it won't work. When I runt the method nothing happens. And what I want is that the client get's the downloaded file

Comment: But you're running this action from a browser window, yes? By "nothing happens" you mean white screen in browser?

Answer (score 0):

I've used a httphandler for sending the byte file object to the browser.

This link should help, [Generating a file, then launching a secure download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725625/generating-a-file-then-launching-a-secure-download/725657#725657)

Answer (score 0):

So save the file on the server then transmit it to the user in your controller:

```
return new FilePathResult(myFilePath, 
  "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
```