# OpenXML SDK Spreadsheet starter kits

Tags: excel, sdk, openxml, openxml-sdk, spreadsheetml

I am trying to start working with Excel documents through the OpenXML SDK Spreadsheet API.
But I haven't found any good guides or even examples on how to create a xlsx file from scratch. Only how to open an existing document and modify it.

I have been thinking on having a empty template document and make a copy of it an then begin my proccessing on it. But it doesent feel right. It might be easier but I not comfortable using a technique I dont feel that I understand "pretty" good at least.

So my question is: Does anyone have any good tips on articles or books or any other type of resource that explains the API?

Thanks in advance.
/johan

Comment: Please use the 'excel-2007' tag rather than 'xlsx'. Watch the suggestion prompts when tagging your questions: any tag with a number less than 10 after it's name is probably wrong.

Comment: to me, excel-2007 implies Microsoft Office interop.  Since the OpenXML standard does not rely on Excel at all, I think  SpreadsheetML is a better tag.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your best bet is to download the [OpenXml SDK 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854(office.14).aspx) and install.  Once installed, check the Tools directory for a tool called DocumentReflector.exe.  Using this tool you can "crack open" an existing xslx document (or docx or pptx).  Once opened, the application will show you a treeview of the parts, a panel with the xml for a given part and the code required to generate the document from scratch.

This should give you a great start and get you to really understand the SpreadsheetML syntax (I used this tool to learn WordProcessingML and it REALLY helped!).

Also see [how to create and download excel document using asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643643/how-to-create-and-download-excel-document-using-asp-net)

Comment: I ended up using Synfusions XlsIO component, it a commercial component but money well spent. Recommended for XLSX and XLX creation.

Answer (score 3):

I've got to admit. The OpenXml SDK is nice, but there's still a lot to creating a blank spreadsheet.

However, there is a set of Helper Classes available on codeplex called [simpleooxml](http://simpleooxml.codeplex.com/)

Very little in the way of documentation, but this [blog post](http://bloggingdotnet.blogspot.com/2009/05/getting-started-with-simple-ooxml.html) shows how to create a new spreadsheet without having to have an existing template.

I've found it works pretty well.

Answer (score 2):

http://openxmldeveloper.org is a pretty good resource, with concepts and code samples in various programming languages

Answer (score 0):

On MSDN there is now pretty good documentation on all the classes, ie: [SpreadsheetDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.packaging.spreadsheetdocument.aspx) and a couple walkthroughs like ['how to create a spreadsheet'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff478153.aspx).