# Create and populate Excel file in c# code behind

Tags: c#, excel

Can anyone direct me to a place where I can learn a little bit about creating a .xslx file in code behind then populating it.  I would need to create new worksheets as well.

I would be using a text box and parsing the data therein to populate the excel spreadsheet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6E744E5-36E9-45F5-8D8C-331DF206E0D0&displaylang=en).  It provides a slightly higher level API than simply the formidable Open XML specification.  Download both packages - the tools are useful for experimenting.

Here are some links that should get you started using this SDK:

- [Getting Started with the Open XML
  SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb456488.aspx)
- [Creating Spreadsheet document using
  OpenXML SDK](http://openxmldeveloper.org/forums/thread/1816.aspx)
- [Creating Documents
  by Using the Open XML Format SDK
  2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd452407%28office.12%29.aspx)

The question [OpenXML SDK Spreadsheet starter kits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824056/openxml-sdk-spreadsheet-starter-kits) also has some great links.

Answer (score 0):

I used a few SDK's when I had to do it, and unfortunately many of them worked but had issues with some security when you open it in Excel again.

I eventually settled for good old COM interop with Excel.

This [Interop Arcticle](http://dotnetperls.com/excel-interop) will help you get started.

I just created a nice ExcelHelper class to hide all the ugly COM syntax and handle the memory for me.